# Check the username and the password of a community user

Tags: apex, community, api, passwords

I have a community and inside, I have a form to allow to the user to change his password.

To do that, the user has to enter his old password, the new password and the confirmation of the new password (usual).

I would like to know if there is a way to check that the username and the old password are valid.

I read this article (https://developer.secure.force.com/cookbook/recipe/verifying-password) but my problem is that the community user doesn't have a security token so it doesn't work (the profile has the permission "API Enabled").

Do you know if there is a way to test the username and the password via API for a community user please?

I can't user the standard feature because my client want something else.

Comment: Why not use `changePassword(newPassword, verifyNewPassword, oldPassword)` from [Sites system class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm)?

Comment: Are logging into the community with the right endpoint (https://community-domain/path-prefix/Soap/c/37.0/ instead of https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/37.0/) and is the orgId specified in the SOAP Header "LoginScopeHeader"? See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm in the Section "Authenticating Customer Community Users in Salesforce Communities".  

Of course using changePassword as suggestd by Raul is much better...

Comment: I didn't know the method Site.changePassword(), it is completely what I was looking for.

It works, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is the APEX method `Site.changePassword()`.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm